# "Harvesting" a graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Suppose we have a graph where each edge is paired with a pair of numbers (cost to travel down that edge,time to travel down that edge), and each vertex is paired with a pair of numbers (gain,time) where the time associated with each vertex is an integer representing the amount of moves on the graph before the gain can be collected again from that vertex.

When can an optimal circuit through the graph be formed (in terms of maximizing average profit/time)?

Comment: Are you asking whether an optimal cycle exists, or how to find the optimal cycle?

Comment: Primarily I am asking for existence and uniqueness, an algorithm to find such a cycle would be a secondary objective. That said, I'm mainly just interested in whether or not this is a question that is resolved or being actively studied.

Comment: Assuming this is a finite graph, there are only finitely many circuits, so if there is any circuit there must be one where the objective takes its maximum value.  There is no reason to think that it would be unique.